# How can I join n selected elements to create an html fragment in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple selector that selects first 2 paragraphs

```
$("p").slice(0,2);
```

Now I want to join these two paragrahps so I can get html fragment like this

```
<p>first</p>
<p>second</p>
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the HTML fragment then try creating an dummy object, append to it and get the HTML.

```
$('<div />').append($("p").slice(0,2).clone()).html()
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7xLTe/

Comment: One question though, what does clone do in this case? I tried the fiddle removing the clone and it worked just fine.

Comment: @AkshatJiwanSharma `.clone` clones the returned `p`, removing clone would simply remove the original `p` as it was added to the dummy object.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this -

```
$("p").slice(0,2).appendTo('body');
```

Fiddle `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/VthKf/

Comment: What is that `get` and `join` doing? I believe `$("p").slice(0,2).appendTo('body')` would be the same.

Comment: get returns a pure js dom array and join concats the elemtns of the array

Comment: .join('') returns string, so what is its purpose here?